# How to enable Facebook post “seen by” feature?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Some groups in Facebook have the “seen by” feature for all post—mine doesn’t.

How can I add this feature to my group? Is this related to number of members or admins?

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook Community Forum](http://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=394642903951964) already has the answer: If your  group is less than 250 members, "seen by" feature is automatically activated (you will not able to find it in group setting). Once your group members exceed 250, this feature will be disabled.